# Long text sentence are not displayed (ggforce + geom_mark_circle)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I am playing with the `ggforce` library and I have difficulties with displaying long text. When the text to display is a bit longer, it disappears from the plot (see example #2). Is there a way to fix that?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_mark_circle(aes(color = Species, label = "Small sentence"),
    expand = unit(0.2, "mm")
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

This does not work

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_mark_circle(aes(color = Species, label = "This is a very long text to display"),
                   expand = unit(0.2, "mm")
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If you are using RStudio, try clicking on zoom. It should show the text

Comment: Thank you it works. However, it is still missing when I `ggsave` to a pdf or png.

Comment: How about this: `p <-ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_mark_circle(aes(color = Species, label = "This is a very long text to display"),
                   expand = unit(0.2, "mm")
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_minimal()

ggsave("prueba.pdf",p, width = 10, height = 10)`

Comment: This work for this specific example. But in mine with real data I really have to increase the width and the height of the pdf to see the annotation, even though there is plenty of space to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_wrap()` in the `tidyverse`

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_mark_circle(
    aes(color = Species, label = str_wrap("This is a very long text to display", 20)),
    expand = unit(0.2, "mm")
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will use that even it was supposed to wrap automatically! "# Long descriptions are automatically wrapped to fit into the width"

Comment: You could add it as an issue on their github
https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues